# 2003 ML500 Reprogramming Key

Tags: mercedes-benz, ignition-key

I have a 2003 Mercedes ML500 truck. I bought a replacement key from a third party and now I'm trying to program it. How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for someplace to get your key programmed? The only place which can do it is a Mercedes dealership.

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/3684/4152 ... does this by any chance help you out?

Comment: Go to a Mercedes Dealership and get it programmed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is.. you are screwed.  Unless you know someone who has a bootleg software program, you can not get any fob from any source programed for a 2003 ML500 (or most any of the ML's of that era) programed.

If I am wrong, someone please tell me where I can as I have 2 ML's that need additional fobs programmed.

Thank you!