# Lost key for Mercedes 2000 c240 need replacement

Tags: ignition-key

Trying to find a cheaper way to get another key they are very pricey. Don't have away to get my car towed to dealership

Comment: I think the dealership or a locksmith is going to get involved no matter what. the key needs to be added into the cars list of accepted keys.

Comment: You may be able to get a key electronic guts off eBay or similar at a cheaper price, but making it work with your [expensive German] vehicle may be problematic.  Make sure you have replaced the key fob battery first, as these don't last forever.  @Ben is correct (as usual) and this is unfortunately a job for a specialist, or a geek like me that wouldn't have asked the question. (No disrespect intended.)  If you are adventurous you may be able to google how to train a new key code to your MB c240.   Best of luck!

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3681/6299